# TypeScript error in directory/node_modules/@antv/g6-core/lib/types/index.d.ts(24,37): Type expected. TS1110

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, antd

After cloning the repo from GitHub and installing packages by running yarn install, when I'm run the project getting this error. I tried to update react script latest, doesn't work. Also, tried to update typescript 4.1.2 doesn't work.

- Node v: 14.17.3
- Npm v: 6.14.13
- Yarn v: 1.22.10

[image]

**This is my package.json**

```
{
    "name": "zis3-frontend",
    "version": "4.6.41.3",
    "created": "2022-03-15 20:23:03",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@ant-design/charts": "^1.0.8",
        "@ant-design/icons": "^4.1.0",
        "@types/i18next": "^13.0.0",
        "@types/react-highlight-words": "^0.16.1",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.8",
        "@types/react-router": "^5.1.7",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
        "antd": "^4.10.2",
        "antd-button-color": "^1.0.3",
        "antd-mask-input": "^0.1.13",
        "array-move": "^4.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "fast-xml-parser": "^3.20.3",
        "i18next": "17.0.1",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^4.1.1",
        "i18next-http-backend": "^1.0.8",
        "moment": "^2.25.3",
        "node-sass": "4.14.1",
        "query-string": "^6.13.0",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-highlight-words": "^0.16.0",
        "react-i18next": "10.11.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
        "react-json-pretty": "^2.2.0",
        "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "react-router": "^5.1.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
        "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
        "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "sweetalert2": "^11.3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build && REACT_APP_BUILD_VERSION=$(./ci/get_fe_version.py) && sed -i -- 's/%REACT_APP_BUILD_VERSION%/'$REACT_APP_BUILD_VERSION'/g' build/index.html && echo React Build Version = $REACT_APP_BUILD_VERSION",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "postcssSortingConfig": {
        "properties-order": "alphabetical"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "prettier": "2.0.5",
        "stylelint": "^13.3.3",
        "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^7.0.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
        "stylelint-statement-max-nesting-depth": "^2.0.1",
        "typescript": "^3.9.7"
    }
}
```

**TS Config**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost", "es5", "es6"],
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noLib": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "filesGlob": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx", "!./node_modules/**"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"],
  "rules": {
    "quotemark": "single",
    "autoFixOnSave": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eg. I did the following
npm uninstall -D typescript (This uninstalled 3.9.7 version)
npm i -D typescript@4.2.4

This fixed the problem